# Whatsapp Business Product Catalog permission to access error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I´m using the Facebook Dev Explorer to upload a catalog to a Whatsapp Business account.
I created manually a catalog by the android app, and now I want to check the catalog by the endpoint and it throws this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) You do not have permission to access this field.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "A4eRfKAc3aauWYEZEqalmFR"
  }
}
```

Before that I tried to push a catalog_id to the whatsapp business account and throws the same error. If I make a Get or Post to another endpoint like message template there are´t any error.

I use an whatsapp account linked with a facebook page what I am owned.

Comment: Is this issue still unresolved??

Comment: i think you can't access or use an existing what's app number 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started/migrate-existing-whatsapp-number-to-a-business-account